WiX v4 bootstrapper MajorUpgrade no longer passes -quiet command line
In my WiX v3 custom BA, when an upgrade occurred the BA would pass the -quiet command line flag to the previously installed version so it could uninstall silently. This seems to no longer be the case in v4.
My old v3 BA was dependent on this flag to know when to run the upgrade uninstall silently. I realize there are other (and better) ways to detect a silent install in v4, but my already deployed v3 installers are looking for -quiet.
Nothing about this change was mentioned in the docs as far as I could see, but testing both mine and sample BA apps I found online, this new behavior seemed consistent.
Is there any way to get the "-quiet" upgrade command line back?
